# Get data in Ajax doesnt work

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, send

I have this Jquery Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#check_button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/adcontent.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "id=<?php echo $id; ?>",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function (data) {
                    $('#check_quest_button_div').html("<img src='/images/icons/loading.gif' title='Please wait' alt='Please wait' />");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is my PHP code in includes/adcontent.php:

```
if (!isset($id) && isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_GET['id']));
}
echo $id;
```

But with this code I have an error message. The script doesnt send the GET data. What is the problem?

Comment: Don't pass it as data, pass it as a query param (after the includes/adcontent.php add a `?id=<?php echo $id; ?>`

Comment: Can you wireshark it and make sure that the request is being made?

Comment: Yes, the request is Ok. If I place the code echo "ok";, I can see it.

Comment: And this is my error: Undefined variable: id I can also see that the GET is empty: [_GET] => Array
        (
        )

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#check_button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/adcontent.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>",
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function (data) {
                    $('#check_quest_button_div').html("<img src='/images/icons/loading.gif' title='Please wait' alt='Please wait' />");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Jordy - Do you atleast see the request going through?

Comment: Yes, the request is Ok. If I place the code echo "ok";, I can see it.

Comment: And this is my error: Undefined variable: id I can also see that the GET is empty: [_GET] => Array
        (
        )

Comment: "Undefined variable: id" when you click on check_button?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/adcontent.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>",
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (data) {
        $('#check_quest_button_div').html("<img src='/images/icons/loading.gif' title='Please wait' alt='Please wait' />");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Do you see the alert?

Comment: Yes, i see the alert with the right variable. Very strange, because it doesn't work if I replace your 'success-code' with my code.

Comment: Then there's probably an error with that code. I also changed how you're sending data to the server, so that would do it too. I'm sending them as query strings, you were sending them as body data, which is not allowed in a GET request as per the spec.

Comment: Well, I have the solution. I should also change the .load() code with ?id=<?php echo $id; ?>. It was my fault. Sorry, but many thanks for your help!!!